# make a copy of a Map with new items inserted in F#

Tags: f#

if I have a record:

```
let r = { a = 1; b = 2 }
```

I can do:

```
let r2 = { r with b = 3 }
```

but is there an equivalent with Maps?

like:

```
let m = Map ["a", 1; "b", 2]
```

would allow me to do:

```
let m2 = m with ["a", 3]
```

what is the most F#-ish way to achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Map.add` replaces a key if it already exists:

```
let m2 = Map.add "a" 3 m
```

Comment: so if I want to edit x entries, it will have to make x copies of the Map?

Comment: @Thomas - `Map.add` doesn't copy the map, only the path from the root to the inserted leaf node. The complexity of `add` is O(ln N).

Comment: @Thomas if you wan't to update more than one entry, you'll need to `Map.add` them one at a time. This is quite easy to do using a `fold`; e.g. `[ (key1, value1); (key2, value2) ] |> List.fold (fun m' (k, v) -> Map.add k v m') m` will add the two key-value pairs `(key1, value1)` and `(key2, value2)` and return the updated map.